# Captcha with $, #, £, €, &, % characters?

Tags: captcha

Is it a good idea to have a captcha with $, #, £, €, &, % characters in it? (the users will be university students ("freshman"?).

Comment: Making your own captcha is a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: @delnan, you can add new characters to this captcha (has a confiration file) http://www.dbscripts.net/imageverification/demo/

Comment: So copypasting a simplistic (proof-of-concept, it seems) implementation isn't as inferior to using a widely-used, tested implementation as whipping up your own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, See for example the [Apple US keyboard](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC184LL/A?fnode=MTY1NDA1Mg&mco=MTMzNzg5MDM) How do you enter £ and € ?

Answer (score 3):

What would be the point? Aren't regular captchas good enough?

Also, remember that different users may have different keyboard layouts. What if I don't have `€` on my keyboard, for example?

Comment: @ilhan: And how would adding 6 new characters fix it, exactly?

Comment: @skaffman, I don't know, I'm trying. In fact I'm thinking to use nonenglish characters like Ü and Ş but the foreign students won't be able to pass the captcha :/

Comment: @ilhan: If you think Captcha is broken, you're not going to improve it by changing the characters. If it's broken, it's broken, and you need to use something else.